# Is there any downtime if I switch my GKE cluster from zonal to regional?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

Is there any downtime If I switch my Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud from a regional to a non regional one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the zonal cluster to Regional Cluster. You have to recreate the cluster in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what do you mean by switch.

You can change [default region or zone](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/changing-default-zone-region), which will only work on new resources:

> Newly created resources, like VM instances, will be deployed to the selected region and/or zone

This can be done using following `gcloud` command:

```
$ gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata google-compute-default-region=europe-west1,google-compute-default-zone=europe-west1-b
```

After which you should reinitialize your `default` configuration using `$ gcloud init`.

You can also [Move an instance between zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones) which will cause some downtime.

I also recommend reading about [Regions and Zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones).